# filter Datatable based on a specific column in metroTextBox_TextChanged

Tags: c#

I am trying to filter datatable which in the body based on a specific column in metroTextBox_TextChanged.

```
    public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DbDataAdapter arg_17_0 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from monitor_users", this.connection2);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        arg_17_0.Fill(dataTable);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }



    // Token: 0x0600209F RID: 8351 RVA: 0x00063FEB File Offset: 0x000621EB

    private void metroTextBox_0_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs p1)
    {

        // What should the code be here ?
    }
```

Comment: Use a [DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thx a lot . you made my day .